# Authentication in Laravel Modification needed

Tags: php, laravel

I have a bit more of a general question on how to handle Authentication Modifications in laravel properly.

The default User Class might not be sufficient for me, to fulfil the requirements I have. Therefore I would need additional fields in the User Table. Of course I can adapt the class. But what happens when:

1) Laravel will get updated to a new version. Then I assume all the changes will be overwritten?

2) When I use Authentication and register a person, the Authentication Controller adds the user to the users table. But should I actually change code in the Authentication Controller? Isn't that messing with code, I should not touch directly?

What is the better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) I would go and [create my own middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#defining-middleware), no changes will ever be overwritten on any new version of Laravel, just don't touch the vendor files (the ones you cloned from Composer)

You can always [write your own service provider for that middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/providers#writing-service-providers), sounds bombastic, but it's truly very simple.

2.) If you want to take the route of redefining your User Model/Routes/Controllers etc, that is not tampering at all, those are part of your project files, your created it with `make:auth` (As far as I remember the command.) Again, allow me to re-iterate that only vendor (and node_modules if you use front end packages) are the folders you shoudn't tamper with.

3.) Overall, I am only assuming your are coming from WordPress, where in a CMS, being dependent on certain core features, upgrading is neccessary where some actions and filters could go awry from ver to ver as to dependencies with other functions that are out of the scope of your project, yet in Laravel, once you start your project, it's set and good for life. You can still have a project with Laravel 5.1 and it could work great, even though Laravel 5.6 is out, you do **not** need to "upgrade" Laravel.

Comment: excellent answer and thanks for the patience of explaining it in so much detail. Super appreciated.